# Nested ng-repeat not working properly

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code

```
<div class="list-group">
   <a class="list-group-item" href="" ng-repeat="q in data.items">
     <i ng-if="q.glyph" class="fa fa-{{::q.glyph}} m-r-sm"></i>
     <i ng-if="!q.glyph" class="fa fa-chevron-right m-r-sm"></i> {{::q.label}}</a>

<div>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="i in q.items | orderBy:'label'">
      <i class="fa fa-{{::i.glyph}} m-r-sm"></i>
        <i ng-if="::!i.glyph" class=""></i> {{::i.label}}
    </a>
</div>
```

For some reason the second `ng-repeat` `i in q.items` does not render anything to the view. However, I changed the code (next snippet) to iterate through `data.items` **again** which I don't think it's necessary, but it works. What is wrong with the first code?

```
<div class="list-group">
   <a class="list-group-item" href="" ng-repeat="q in data.items">
     <i ng-if="q.glyph" class="fa fa-{{::q.glyph}} m-r-sm"></i>
     <i ng-if="!q.glyph" class="fa fa-chevron-right m-r-sm"></i> {{::q.label}}</a>

<div>
  <div ng-repeat="z in data.items">
    <a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="i in z.items | orderBy:'label'">
      <i class="fa fa-{{::i.glyph}} m-r-sm"></i>
        <i ng-if="::!i.glyph" class=""></i> {{::i.label}}
    </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second ng-repeat should the child of first ng-repeat. In the first example ng-repeat with 'i' is not the child of first one. where as in the second one, ng-repeat with 'i' is child of ng-repeat with 'z'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First snippet is not working because iteration is over above.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <a ng-repeat="q in data.items">
>   {{q.data}}
> </a> <!-- end of iteration -->
> <a ng-repeat="i in q.items"> <!-- You try to iterate an undefined array -->
>   {{i.data}}
> </a>
> ```

Solution could be:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div ng-repeat="q in data.items">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="">
            <i ng-if="q.glyph" class="fa fa-{{::q.glyph}} m-r-sm"></i>
            <i ng-if="!q.glyph" class="fa fa-chevron-right m-r-sm"></i> {{::q.label}}
        </a>
        <div>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="i in q.items | orderBy:'label'">
                <i class="fa fa-{{::i.glyph}} m-r-sm"></i>
                <i ng-if="::!i.glyph" class=""></i> {{::i.label}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```